# Can I retrieve more than 20 post title names on Tumblr? (via JSON)

Tags: json, get, tumblr

I made a script to retrieve the strings of all the post titles of one of my blogs. The problem is that i can't retrieve more than 20 title.

Theoritically, http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1  says: "The most recent 20 posts are included by default. You may pass these optional GET parameters: .... num - The number of posts to return. The default is 20, and the maximum is 50. ..... "

**so should i be able to get the maximum 50?**

My GET code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/var-lak.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=(my-api-key)text?limit=50&format=text",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
    //.....
```

Thanks in advance,
Attila

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, you are passing wrong URL there. GET parameters mentioned in the documentation are separated by & sign in the address, so in:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/var-lak.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=(my-api-key)text?limit=50&format=text
```

You are passing to the server following GET variables:

```
api_key = (my-api-key)text?limit=50
format = text
```

By the docs to v2 API, you have to pass *limit* variable, so you should provide:

```
api_key = (my-api-key)
limit = 50
format = text
```

That means the URL should look like:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/var-lak.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=(my-api-key)&limit=50&format=text
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved it, and now i'm having up to 50 titles!

Comment: If you need more than 50, you can take advantage of `offset` that allows you to start from a specific quantity.

Comment: you mean offset as a variable, such as "limit" or "format" ? That will be useful after a while.

I'll check that out thanks!